# How to mock Request.form in Web api

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-web-api, httprequest, rhino-mocks, request.form

I am trying to write some unit tests for my ApiController and faced some issues.

Here is my TestMethod

```
     [TestMethod]
        public void CustomerController_AddUnitTest()
        {


            var custid = Guid.NewGuid();
            var customers = new Customer() { CustomerName = "Enterprise", CustomerId = custid };
            var rmContext = MockRepository.GenerateMock<HttpContextBase>();
            var rmRequest = MockRepository.GenerateMock<HttpRequestBase>();
            rmContext.Stub(x => x.Request).Return(rmRequest);
            var FormData = new NameValueCollection { { "FirstName", "Jonathan" }, { "LastName", "Danylko" } };
            rmRequest.Stub(r => r.Form).Return(FormData);
            rmContext.Stub(p => p.Request).Return(rmRequest);
            var forms = rmContext.Request.Form;

> // here i am able to get forms value but i couldn't pass these value
> to main controller

            var mockRepository = MockRepository.GenerateMock<ICustomerService>();
            mockRepository.Stub(x => x.Add(new Customer())).IgnoreArguments().Return(1);
            _customerController = new CustomerController(mockRepository);
            var result = _customerController.CustomerAdd();
            Assert.IsNotNull(result);
        }
```

This is my controller code looks like

```
  public int CustomerAdd()
    {
        var localhost = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Authority;
        var formData = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["FormData"];
        JavaScriptSerializer json_serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        var customer = json_serializer.Deserialize<Customer>(formData);
        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Files.Count > 0)
        {
            HttpPostedFile file = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[0];
            string fileName = customer.CustomerName.Trim() + "_" + file.FileName;
            var filePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(Constants.FileUploadImagePath + fileName);
            file.SaveAs(filePath);
            customer.Logo = fileName;
        }
        return _iCustomerService.Add(customer);
    }
```

I want to pass mock data to  `var formData = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["FormData"];`

Can anyone have an idea to resolve this issues??..I literally fed up on this task.

Comment: The method under test is poorly designed and is tightly coupled to static dependencies which make it difficult to test. Try to avoid tightly coupling your code to `HttpContext`.

Comment: yes i knew it. But i don't know how to mock this line of code

Comment: var formData = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["FormData"];

Comment: I tried everything but sometimes our ways are not sufficient to find the correct answer....

Answer (score 0):

Pull the line out into a separate (virtual) method, then in your tests, use a partial mock of your controller where you've stubbed the new method to return your mock data. (This is called a "test seam" FYI).

Something like this:

```
public int CustomerAdd()
{
    var localhost = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Authority;
    var formData = GetFormData()["FormData"];
    JavaScriptSerializer json_serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    var customer = json_serializer.Deserialize<Customer>(formData);
    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Files.Count > 0)
    {
        HttpPostedFile file = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[0];
        string fileName = customer.CustomerName.Trim() + "_" + file.FileName;
        var filePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(Constants.FileUploadImagePath + fileName);
        file.SaveAs(filePath);
        customer.Logo = fileName;
    }
    return _iCustomerService.Add(customer);
}

public virtual NameValueCollection GetFormDatat()
{
     return HttpContext.Current.Request.Form;
}
```

Then use this in your test:

```
_customerController = MockRepository.GeneratePartialMock<CustomerContoller>();
_customerController.Stub(c => c.GetFormData()).Return(yourFakeFormData);
```

Alternatively, you could do the same thing, but for usages of the Context object.

Comment: As a general note, you never want your production code to take a reference to your mock framework types directly. In the original post you show the controller class taking the mock repository as a constructor parameter - this should never happen. The mock framework is intended to mock the types you actually use so your production doesn't need to know about your test code.